# vuejs component video path not rendering from data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

This is my data:

```
data() {
   return {
      main: {
         bgVideo: '../../assets/src/homepage.mp4',
      }
   }
}
```

This is my component:

```
<template>
    <video autoplay muted loop>
        <source :src="main.bgVideo" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</template>
```

When I hardcode the path ('../../assets/src/homepage.mp4') in the video src, it works.

When I try to pass the path from the data, it fails to render. There are no errors on the page itself, other than a blank canvas where the background video is supposed to be.

This is the strange part–When I hardcode the path into the video src, the Inspect Element renders the path [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJqW4.png). However, this actually works and renders the video onto the page.

When I attempt to pass the path via the data, it renders the path [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K22Lf.png) and fails to render on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is being built with webpack which is configured with [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) to copy referenced assets in the template source to a destination folder and the `src` path is replaced with the path to the new file. When `src` is bound to a dynamic value, webpack can't know what the asset file is at build time, so no transformation occurs, and at runtime `src` is set to `../../assets/src/homepage.mp4` but there is no file at that location being served by [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) (which is the development web server that runs when you run your app in development mode).

You need to tell webpack to load the asset by importing the module in code (either with `require` or ES6 `import`):

```
data() {
  return {
    main: {
      bgVideo: require('../../assets/src/homepage.mp4'),
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked with the ES6 import command and used :src="main.bgVideo" to call it. Thank you!